# Stop JQuery Opacity scroll-based effect after object reaches 100% opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to the Apple News wherein a photo fades in on scroll, but once it's reached 100% opacity, it won't fade back out.[This video demonstrates the fade in:](https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/news-publisher/videos/fade-in-true.mp4) However it doesn't demonstrate that it stays completely faded in.

I have the fade-in effect already working, I'm just not sure how to keep the opacity at 100% once it reaches that. I've added some mock-code below of what I have, though for whatever reason it doesn't seem to execute  correctly on stackoverflow? [It does work on codepen though](https://codepen.io/ironorrfitness/pen/moPJNX)

```js
function fadeIn() {
  
  $(document).scroll(function(){

  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  var parallaxTop = $('#fade1').offset().top;
  var parallaxStart = parallaxTop * .1;
  var opacity1 = (scrollPos - parallaxStart);
    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= parallaxStart) {
    $('#fade1').css('opacity' , 0 + opacity1);
    }
    
  })
}

fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: block; width:300px;">
<h1>Take Charge</h1>
<h4>Transform your body with a personal trainer in 2019</h4>
</div>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
  <div id="fade1" style="display: block; width:300px;">
<h1>Take Charge</h1>
<h4>Transform your body with a personal trainer in 2019</h4>
    <p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br><p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
  </body>
```

Comment: Before modifying the css check the value of the opacity of the element using  `$('#fade1').css('opacity') < 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to achieve what you're looking for and prevent the element from fading back out once it has faded in.

#### Return early if opacity is at 100%

If the opacity is already at 1.0 then you don't want to change it so you could just return early from the scroll callback if you detect that.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

  // NOTE: Check the opacity and don't change it if the element has
  // already faded in completely
  if($('#fade1').css('opacity') === 1) return;

  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  var parallaxTop = $('#fade1').offset().top;
  var parallaxStart = parallaxTop * .1;
  var opacity1 = (scrollPos - parallaxStart)/600;

  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= parallaxStart) {
    $('#fade1').css('opacity' , 0 + opacity1);
  }

});
```

Or

#### Unbind the event once the element is faded in

If it's expected that the element will never have to fade back in you could just remove the event that

```
function scrollCallback(){

  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  var parallaxTop = $('#fade1').offset().top;
  var parallaxStart = parallaxTop * .1;
  var opacity1 = (scrollPos - parallaxStart)/600;

  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= parallaxStart) {
    $('#fade1').css('opacity' , 0 + opacity1);

    // NOTE: If we've faded in completely then we don't need the event anymore
    if (opacity1 >= 1.0) {
      $(document).unbind('scroll', scrollCallback);        
    }

  }

};

$(document).bind('scroll', scrollCallback);
```

Hopefully one of those options works for you!

Comment: Thanks! the 2nd option works perfectly. For what it's worth, there's a minor error in the 2nd, should be: if (opacity1 >= 1.0) (to align the variable). Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Glad it works. Do you mind marking the answer as accepted? And good catch -- I'll fix the post.